# Compile php with ldap

Tags: php, ldap, linux-mint

I'm on Linux Mint - i can't compile php with LDAP support

Configure says :

```
checking for LDAP Cyrus SASL support... yes
configure: error: Cannot find ldap libraries in /usr/lib.
```

But every -dev libs seems to be installed :

```
 dpkg -l *ldap* | grep ii
ii  ldap-utils                                    2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.1                        OpenLDAP utilities
ii  ldaptor-utils                                 0.0.43+debian1-6ubuntu1                    command-line LDAP utilities
ii  libaprutil1-ldap                              1.3.12+dfsg-3                              Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - LDAP Driver
ii  libkldap4                                     4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1                         library for accessing LDAP
ii  libldap-2.4-2                                 2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.1                        OpenLDAP libraries
ii  libldap2-dev                                  2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.1                        OpenLDAP development libraries
ii  libnet-ldap-perl                              1:0.4300-2ubuntu1                          client interface to LDAP servers
ii  libsasl2-modules-ldap                         2.1.25.dfsg1-3ubuntu0.1                    Cyrus SASL - pluggable authentication modules (LDAP)
ii  php5-ldap                                     5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4                          LDAP module for php5
ii  python-ldaptor                                0.0.43+debian1-6ubuntu1                    pure-Python library for LDAP operations
```

This is not the first time it breaks, each time with some new strange location for the libs or some new special packages, or whatever... Has any of you found out for this time ? This is php 5.4.7.

Thanks,

Comment: please provide the full pathname of that needed lib, compare it with it's requirements and in case it differs, place a symlink or specify with switch.

Answer (score 5):

Believe it or not, configure fails to find ldap.so which is under /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

So i made those links : (liblber is a friend of libldap)

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s i386-linux-gnu/libldap.so
ln -s i386-linux-gnu/liblber.so
```

And configure succeed. The bad thing is 'make' don't work, because :

```
/usr/bin/ld: ext/ldap/.libs/ldap.o: undefined reference to symbol 'ber_strdup@@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'ber_strdup@@OPENLDAP_2.4_2' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Erreur 1
```

It seems to be a bug in PHP - i've seen some others like that fixed by PHP devs in the past.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and it didn't resolve itself until i ALSO sym linked the liblber-2.4.so.2 file

Comment: I had the same problem. Linking `libldap.so`, `liblber.so`, and `liblber-2.4.so.2` into `/usr/lib`, then doing `make clean` and re-running `./configure` and `make` fixed it for me. Thank you!